# How can I monetize with AdMobs a libGDX game made with AIDE?

Tags: monetization

I have created a libGDX game with the AIDE IDE Android app. The game is working fine so I will be uploading it to the Play Store to make money.

I'd like to use AdMob ads, how would I integrate it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Linux Journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/aide%E2%80%94developing-android-android), you need to purchase the premium version of AIDE.

*"AIDE is distributed under a freemium model. The free version allows you to develop, compile and run your code. It also allows you to install to the device on which AIDE is running. However, if you want to generate APK files that can be used to install onto other devices, you need to purchase the full version."*

Next, you need to abide to the [Apache 2 License](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/LICENSE) of libGDX, which doesn't require much, if anything. I don't see a NOTICE text file in the libGDX source, and giving credit is non-mandatory.

So to me it appears that, yes, you can publish commercial apps, and monetize it the way you see fit, once you comply with these two. But you need to verify this yourself.